# Plot a sequence of functions in one plot

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise

I would like to plot a sequence of functions in one plot.

My function is defined piecewise:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{-1, -1 <= x < -(1/n)}, {n x, -(1/n) <= x <= 1/n}, {1, 
 1/n < x <= 1}}];
```

I would like to plot the functions for let's say

```
n = {1,2,3}
```

in one plot.

How could I do that?

My ideas were to use Map, Apply or MapApply but all of them did not work.

Comment: Using Map: `Plot @@ {f[x] /. n -> # & /@ {1,2,3}, {x, -5, 5}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[f, n, x]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{-1, -1 <= x < -(1/n)}, {n x, -(1/n) <= x <= 
      1/n}, {1, 1/n < x <= 1}}];

Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. {{n -> 1}, {n -> 2}, {n -> 3}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f[n_][x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{-1, -1 <= x < -(1/n)}, {n x, -(1/n) <= x <= 1/n}, {1, 
     1/n < x <= 1}}];
Plot[Table[f[n][x], {n, 3}] // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}]
```